# how to set auto increment feature into a pdf file using java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have the Java code to generate a table in a PDF file, but it is not able to generate more than one page even if more fields were needed.

How would I add auto increment feature for pages?

This the code which I'm refering.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
    String[][] content = { { "a", "b", "1" }, { "c", "d", "2" },
            { "e", "f", "3" }, { "g", "h", "4" }, { "i", "j", "5" } };
    drawTable(page, contentStream, 700, 100, content);
    contentStream.close();
    doc.save("test.pdf");
}
```

Comment: I assume the full code is located [here](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2010/10/creating-tables-with-pdfbox.html)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this particular piece of code is that you are passing a single page to the `drawTable` method.  You would have to calculate before calling `drawTable` in the main method whether multiple pages are needed and create the pages there.  This might require some slight modification of the `drawTable` method to accept say a List of PDPage instead of a single PDPage in the event that more than one page is necessary.  So the way `drawTable` is implemented, no there would be no way to automatically handle it, but with a little math is should be doable to accomplish.